# Show two decimal digits in float with one decimal digit

Tags: ruby

I have money in database stored as `cents` via integer type.  When displaying: I convert it to a float because I want to display the amount in dollar amounts. I always want to display the number with two digits:

ex:

```
5000 => 50.00
500  => 5.00
50   => 0.50
5    => 0.05
0    => 0.00
```

The toughest one is getting the `50` to convert to `0.50` because since it is a float it wants to convert to `0.5`.

Current method which doesn't work:

```
def cents_to_currency_string
  return if cents.nil?
  (cents.to_f / 100)
end
```

Comment: Don't store currency as a float. It's never a good idea. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) and/or [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/14/currency-rounding-errors/).

Comment: @EliSadoff it isn't stored as a float.  It is stored as an integer.  I am simply displaying it as a float. I updated question for clarity.

Comment: I misread the question.

Comment: I gave an answer. I don't really think that it needs to be displayed as a float. It's easier, and looks better, to just interpolate it as an integer.

Comment: good point, no reason to display as float.  string is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking advantage of your own implementation:

```
def cents_to_currency_string(cents)
  return if cents.nil?
  dollars = cents.to_f/100
  '%.2f' % dollars
end
```

Comment: `cents_to_currency_string 50 => 50.00` not what OP wants thus wrong

Comment: @muistooshort look into expected output in OP :)

Comment: Don't forget the `to_f` call on `cents` or you'll get stuck in integer division. `String#%` OTOH is the only sane way to approach this problem.

Comment: now `cents_to_currency_string 50
=> "0.00"` not yet there :)

Comment: Just use the version 2 of your answer (i.e. my edit) and you are fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just a little bit edit your method:

```
def cents_to_currency_string(cents)    
    return if cents.nil? 
    (cents.to_f / 100).to_s.ljust(4,'0')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a few different ways. The easiest way is to do something like this

```
def display(n)
  if n % 100 < 10
    "$#{n/100}.0#{n%100}"
  else 
    "$#{n/100}.#{n%100}"
  end
end
```

And then you can display it like this

```
puts centize(n)
```

Comment: `centize 50 => " 50"` not what OP wants thus wrong :)

Comment: Did you read the implementation I wrote? `centize` takes an integer value of cents.

Comment: Sorry @EliSadoff my question probably was not clear.  There is no such column as `dollars`.  The entire amount is stored as cents via integer column in the database.  Otherwise your implementation would work.

Comment: @Neil, ah ok. Let me fix my answer to adjust for that.

Comment: I would recommend you to just read question carefully before trying to offend others with not so much appropriate `let me ask again atata` ;) P.S.`5000 => 50.00` is very clear OP's intent

Comment: @Neil I fixed my answer to account for this.